# reverse list of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, list, object, reverse

I just struggled through the interview question:

Please reverse a list of objects.

Is my solution correct?
How would you analyze this?
Are there more efficient ways to reverse a single object list?

```
var node3 = {data: 3, next: null}
var node3 = {data: 2, next: node3}
var node3 = {data: 1, next: node2}
```

// Logically
// node1.next = node2.next = node3.next = null

```
const function reverse() {
  var node = linkedlist;
  var previous = null;

  while(node) {
        var save = node.next;
        node.next = previous;
        previous = node;
        node = save;
  }
  return previous;   
}
```

// example usage
what if you have a list of thousands of objects

```
var myList = node1
myList = reverse(myList)
myList === node3 is true

myList = reverse(myList)
myList === node1 is true
```

Comment: You have three variables called `node3` is that correct?

Comment: everything is exactly as I got in the interview ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Linked data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_data_structure)
[Linked Lists - Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jQhALI4ujg)

```js
var node3 = { data: 3, next: null };
node3 = { data: 2, next: node3 };
node3 = { data: 1, next: node3 }; // <= your code here is node2
```

```js
// To make it easier to understand I just set the entire LDS directly
// each next is point to next data, null means end of data
let node3 = {
    "data": 1,
    "next": {
        "data": 2,
        "next": {
            "data": 3,
            "next": null
        }
    }
};

function reversLDS(LDS) {
    let newLDS = null; // end of LDS
    while (LDS) { // if not null
        newLDS = {
            data: LDS.data, // read data from LDS
            next: newLDS // set next to previous newLDS(self)
        };
        LDS = LDS.next; // get next LDS
    }
    return newLDS;
}

let reversed = reversLDS(node3);

while (reversed) {
    console.log(reversed);
    reversed = reversed.next;
}
```

`A` = 1st `newLDS`
`B` =  2nd `newLDS`

```js
//↓A　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　↓B
newLDS = { data: LDS.data, next: newLDS };
```

here
`B` is still old `newLDS`
`A` is a new obj

Comment: Thank you! 

What do you think about this way?

`
var reverseList = function(head) {
    let prev = null;
    let current = head;
    while(current) {
      let next = current.next;
      current.next = prev;
      prev = current;
      current = next;
    }
    return prev;
}
`